# nunjucks loop variable filter

Tags: nunjucks

```
var dataArr = [{
    name: 'name',
    value: 'lcat'
}, {
    name: 'score'
    value: '123.852',
    filter: 'round'
},{
    name: 'groups'
    value: [1,2,3,6,0],
    filter: 'sort'
}]

{% for data in dataArr %}
    <div>{{ data[value] | data.filter }}<div>
{% endfor %}
```

The console error: Error: filter not found: data.filter.

How do I write the loop?

Comment: What do you want to generate? How would the generated html ideally look like? BTW: you can use [{% if..%}](http://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#if) to branch the code..

Comment: @xmojmr I want according to the data cycle to HTML.And I can customize to add filter configuration. Now I do't know how to write the filter(| data.filter will complains)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1)** You can use `if` to branch the loop based on a condition observed in the dataset. For example this `Nunjucks` code:

```
{% for data in dataArr %}
    {% if data.filter == 'round' %}
        <div>{{ data.value | round }}</div>
    {% elif data.filter == 'sort' %}
        <div>{{ data.value | sort }}</div>
    {% else %}
        <div>{{ data.value }}</div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

produces this `html` code:

```
<div>lcat</div> <div>124</div> <div>0,1,2,3,6</div>
```

From your dataset.

You can play with it in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xmojmr/gbLLryuz/

---

**(2)** Or you can roll your own filter which will take the arbitrary filter expression string defined in the dataset and inject the code (unprotected) into the page building engine (You can read little bit about why intentionally allowing code injection is not good idea at [Wikipedia: Code injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection))

For example if `env` variable is of type [Nunjucks.Environment](http://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#environment) then adding following filter before you run the `JavaScript` template rendering code

```
env.addFilter('eval', function(value, filterExpression) {
    return env.renderString(
        "{{ filterArgument | " + filterExpression + " }}",
        { filterArgument: value }
    );
});
```

enables the use of simplified equivalent `Nunjucks` code

```
{% for data in dataArr %}
    {% if data.filter %}
        <div>{{ data.value | eval(data.filter) }}</div>
    {% else %}
        <div>{{ data.value }}</div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The above code produces following `html` code:

```
<div>lcat</div> <div>124</div> <div>123.85</div> <div>0,1,2,3,6</div>
```

when applied to the dataset below (notice the new **round(2)**):

```
{
    name: 'name',
    value: 'lcat'
}, {
    name: 'score',
    value: '123.852',
    filter: 'round'
}, {
    name: 'score2',
    value: '123.852',
    filter: 'round(2)'
}, {
    name: 'groups',
    value: [1,2,3,6,0],
    filter: 'sort'
}
```

You can play with it in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xmojmr/jkb7ry9x/1/

---

The way **(1)** is safe and reasonably fast but it assumes that you know the list of allowed custom filters ahead

The way **(2)** is wild, unsafe and slower but enables using of any user-provided filter expression

Comment: If the filter is **round(2)**...
My original intention is to dynamically call a filter,the filter is the user configuration

Comment: @user2632323 See the way **(2)** in my edited answer. Personally I would not follow this path because of the "code injection" problem. If the code works for you and you don't have further questions then click the "accept" button as described in [Help Center > Asking > What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)